# Каким членом предложения является определительное местоимение ''сам'' в следующем предложении?

Tags: грамматика

Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку и **сама** поплыла рядом с ним.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Определительное местоимение САМ часто играет роль   усилительного слова при существительном и личном местоимении: Это был сам император;и является тем же членом предложения, что и усиливаемое слово.

Это предложение с однородными сказуемыми при подлежащем САМА ЛОСИХА, только усилительное слово отделено от подлежащего. При разборе подчёркивается как подлежащее, но самостоятельной синтаксической роли не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. В интернете есть подобные разборы, но ничего путного не нашел.

Comment: Людмила, Грамота.ру говорит, что ''сама" в данном случае часть сказуемого. Вы согласны?

Comment: Ну. если считать, что усиливается сказуемое, то согласна. Видимо, кто как воспринимает, что усиливает это слово, а оно может усиливать и подлежащее, и сказуемое.

Comment: Только смысл тогда изменится, будто бы она самостоятельно поплыла, а по-моему, здесь упор на том, что сама лосиха поплыла, а не лосиха сама(самостоятельно) поплыла.

Answer (score 4):

> Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку и **сама** поплыла рядом с ним.

Каким членом предложения является в этом предложении ***сама?***

По-моему, никаким. Предложение вполне может обойтись и без этого слова:

***Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку и поплыла рядом с ним.***

На мой взгляд, ***сама*** в разбираемом предложении выступает в роли частицы.

Comment: Но в словаре Кузнецова не указано, что "сам'' может выступать в качестве частицы.

Comment: А "сам император" в примере Людмилы?

Comment: Если учитывать, что "сам" является тем же членом, что и усиливаемое слово, то в примере Людмилы "сам'' можно отнести к подлежащему.

Answer (score 1):

### [image: Заголовок]

Ответ Грамоты.Ру. .............................