# Сами себе или самим себе?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, местоимения

Какая форма будет правильной:

наносим урон **сами себе** или **самим себе**?

Допустимы ли оба варианта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагается как вариант:

**(1) *Мы сами себе наносим урон, а не они нам*.**

*Мы сами наносим.* Двунаправленная связь слова «сами» (И.п) с подлежащим «мы» и сказуемым.

**(2) *Мы самим себе наносим урон, а не им*.**

*Самим себе наносим.* Двунаправленная связь слова «самим» (Д.п) с дополнением «себе» и сказуемым.

**Примечание.** Предлагаемое решение соответствует грамматическому материалу по теме двунаправленных связей.

Comment: Подлежащие в (1) не "мы", а "мы сами" или просто "сами", если "мы" опущено.

Comment: Может быть и так, я использовала общую схему для двунаправленных связей. Вы можете подтвердить то, что сказали, какими-нибудь ссылками на источник.

Comment: А в таких предложениях где подлежащее: Даже сами себе мы зачастую врем. По существу, олигархи сами себе определяют ренту.

Comment: Могу подтвердить, но не буду. Мне за это не платят. Но дело даже не в ссылке, просто включите логику - если именительный падеж не является подлежащим, то какие для него варианты остаются в этом предложении?

Comment: Спасибо, а у вас много лишней логики? Тогда давайте сыграем партию: логика против интуиции, ваш ответ против моего.  Приглашаю  вас обозначить  свое мнение в теме обособление сравнительного оборота https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474228/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-как-в-выделенном-предложении  Откажитесь, как я думаю…А по поводу логичности ВАШЕГО суждения я тоже сомневаюсь (есть варианты, которые вы не видите).  Но вы сами, я думаю, разберетесь в этой теме (я ведь здесь тоже забесплатно).

Answer (score 2):

Мой первый ответ пока оставляю на форуме в качестве примера одного из экспресс-решений задачи со словом «сам» с помощью **грамматики** (для интереса). Сейчас же расскажу **об истории вопроса**, а она довольно длинная.

1. **Вот это слово не сайте «Большой вопрос»** (просто один к одному)
   http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1005760-kak-pravilno-sami-sebe-ili-samim-sebe.html

**2. А это наш форум, тоже любопытно**
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420175/Каким-членом-предложения-является-определительное-местоимение-сам-в-следующе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420175/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5)

Там, кстати, есть ответ от **Грамоты.ру**: *Лосиха толкнула лосенка в реку и сама поплыла рядом с ним.* В этом предложении «сама» является **частью сказуемого.**

А это ответ **нашего участника**: Определительное местоимение САМ часто играет роль **усилительного слова** при существительном и личном местоимении: Это был сам император; и является тем же членом предложения, что и усиливаемое слово.

Это предложение с однородными сказуемыми **при подлежащем САМА ЛОСИХА**, только **усилительное** слово отделено от подлежащего. При разборе **подчёркивается** как подлежащее, но самостоятельной синтаксической роли не имеет.

Мнения, как мы видим, разные.

**3. А теперь посмотрим в словарь** [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=сам&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC&all=x)

Там это **указательное местоимение**, а не частица, причем есть разные **варианты**: местоименное прилагательное, местоименное существительное, в значении наречия. И везде многозначность, что тоже важно.

**4. Вывод**

Да, тема на **школьную «диссертацию**» тянет и требует немало времени. Поэтому я ее откладываю в сторону. Но замечу, что все решения и суждения, которые здесь приведены, не имеют убедительной основы, как бы «**в воздухе висят**». Может, поэтому они такие разные. К тому же **в словарь** будто бы никто и не заглядывал, не говоря уж **об учебниках по грамматике**.

И вот мой первый ответ (ниоткуда не списанный и пусть еще далекий от истины) – это **попытка  найти** такую основу с помощью грамматики в теме о двунаправленных связях.

А вам я предлагаю подумать **над этой темой и над ситуацией в целом**, если интересно. Правда, за это не платят…))

Comment: Да какое уж там "мнение" у грамоты, сидят какие-то посредственности и строчат ответы под копирку без какой либо логики, пояснений, оттуда и ошибки. Вообще сайт считаю вредным, так как ни один ответ не мотивируется, а тупо дается инструкция. Сравните ответ Людмилы - настоящего профессионала и скупой, немотивированный ответ грамоты. Вот Людмила это авторитет.

Comment: Вам легче живется,  так как у вас есть авторитеты.  А у меня все мои авторитеты — это словари и учебники для вузов. Ну и еще уверенность в том, что авторитеты мне не очень-то и нужны. Почему-то в моем понимании авторитет и авторитарность — это практически одно и то же. (Авторитарный — основанный на беспрекословном подчинении власти, авторитету.) Что касается Грамоты. ру, то ресурс все-таки контролируется специалистами, многие ориентируются на его мнение. Поэтому не всё там однозначно плохо. А вот один конкретный человек вполне может ошибиться. Но здесь у меня есть вопросы  к обеим сторонам.

Comment: @user190920 Они аргументируют, если об этом попросить. Людмила тоже ерунду писала.

Answer (score 1):

Нанести урон(кому?) — самим себе (дательный падеж).
Второй вариант тоже допустим, но в другом контексте. Сами себе — винительный падеж.

**Оценив так ситуацию, мы сами себя сильно обманули.**

**В результате, выстраивая ложную информационную матрицу они обманули сами себя**.

Хотя, нужно отметить, что ситуация не такая простая, как кажется. НКРЯ очень много примеров, где в дательном п. использована форма: сами себе.

Comment: В каком контексте?

Comment: Не очень понятно, в каком контексте допустимо «сами себе». Пожалуйста, поделитесь источником (справочником, учебником), где об этом можно прочитать.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых - фраза кривая калька с английского, от того и проблемы.

Урон - это слово связанное с потерями в хозяйстве или потери численности популяции животных или растений, военные потери. Употребление слова урон - не корректно. То есть урон наносится тому, что хранится, разбить что-то ценное, уронить. Мышка причинила деду с бабкой урон разбив золотое яичко. Урон - убыль.

Наносить можно краску, можно понести урон, теоретически, но наносить урон - это как нести вылитую воду в ведре.

Урон себе - не логично, значит ты сам себя не ценишь, но нельзя себя не ценить, значит ты сам есть другой, а не ты сам, то есть причинить урон себе нельзя в принципе.

Во-вторых сами себе и самим себе - разные вещи.

самим себе - это значит сам является объектом действия внешней силы, а мы - это субъект, проводник силы.

Сами себе - это когда сами является субъектом. Сами или мы сами. Только тут вопрос. Кто мы? Мы - это у человека расщепление личности что ли?

В английском же любят говорить вместо you(вы, второе множественное) - we(первое множественное). Хотя это тоже немного идиотизм, но тут хотя бы ясно откуда берется первое множественное.

Мы, Иоанн Васильевич Грозный, нанесли урон сами себе. - ну бред же?

Так что прежде, чем думать, почему фраза не клеится, подумать над тем, что это вообще такое. Может это кривоногая химера, которую никакие операции не превратят во что-то ценное.

**Повторение за другими нелогичных и абсурдных фраз не является выражением мысли через речь.**

Думать, что повторять и повторять, что думать - разные вещи.

Очищайте язык от повторения чепухи, тогда и проблем с речью будет меньше. И, возможно, станет понятно, что ты имеешь ввиду, когда говоришь слова.

Ответ. Ни одна из форм не является правильной.

**Дополнение 1:**

Ввиду недопонимания, почему слово *урон* употреблено категорически не верно(многобукв, можно не читать):

*уро́н — род. п. -а, см. рони́ть.* - даже Фасмер согласен, что происходит оно от глагола уронить, ронять.

Почему происходит *урон*, причина *урона*?

Потому что это следствие гравитации(например) или еще какого-то **физического** закона, который может стать причиной. Человек же не может "нанести", но может его вызвать, например - устроить пожар, от которого будет урон хозяйству. Или разрушить дамбу, от которой произойдет наводнение, за счет физического разлива воды, и жители близлежащих сел понесут урон, получат урон, то есть убыль в результате наводнения.

Человек "нанёс урон", нет, урон произошёл в результате разлива воды. Вода нанесла урон? Нет, вода не обладает разумом, чтобы чинить урон, она просто льется вниз.

Но наводнение может устраивать кто-то, кто-то пользуется законами природы, то есть действует косвенно, а не напрямую. Это принципиальное отличие.

Поэтому:

[наиболее великой урон учинился](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkEqIQoICEwQChgyIAoQBSAAKNayvKbSwZoCQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCFQoTChEKA3JlcRIKCgjRg9GA0L7QvTAB#:%7E:text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%2C) - то есть урон есть следствие неких действий, а не "нанесения урона", нельзя воду перечерпать через дамбу её сохранив. Урон может быть причинен как и без умысла, потому что не человек его "несет", а силы природы.

[*нередко причиняет во многих местах как настоящий урон и действительную потерю знатной части скота*,](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkEqIQoICEoQChgyIAoQBSAAKNayvKbSwZoCQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCFQoTChEKA3JlcRIKCgjRg9GA0L7QvTAB#:%7E:text=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8E%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%2C) - урон это "действительная потеря", фактическая. Это не действие неизвестной природы - ущерб, а это фактическая убыль чего-то. Нельзя "нанести урон", потому что нельзя быть уверенным в факте урона, урон происходит по факту убыли, а не по "задумке", нёс одно - принёс другое.

Кто-то нанес ударил, нанес удар - нанес он урон? Не факт: дед бил-бил - не разбил. Но есть удар нанести можно, но нельзя предугадать последствия. А урон нанести нельзя, потому что урон это уже случившееся что-то. Говорящие, "нанести урон" - ломают структуру времени и причинности событий.

Мышка "нанесла урон"? - нет, Мышка махнула хвостиком. А урон произошёл по причине, что Золотое яичко "упало и разбилось". То есть Мышка владела великим искусством нанесения удара хвостом в нужное место и в нужное время, а вовсе не вымышленным искусством "нанесения урона". Ущерб 1 мышка причиняет маленький, она слишком мала, чтобы причинить серьезный ущерб, поэтому должно быть что-то "большее", что объяснит причину столь серьезного урона.

В чем вина мышки, в том что она разбила яичко? - нет. Вина мышки в том, что она махнула хвостиком, и это стало причиной дальнейших событий, причинивших урон. Фраза же "наносить урон" проскакивает всю причинно-следственную цепочку и это не более, чем голословные обвинения мышки, потому что логики в суждении нет. Можно сразу возразить - яичко разбилось само, мышка не виновата. И что-то здравое сказать на этот счёт не выйдет.

Я понимаю, что гуманитарии используют свою замечательную память, а не логику для различения, что грамотно, а что нет. Но память - это еще не всё, можно и ерунду запомнить, а потом повторять. Думайте, что повторяете, уважаемые.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146788/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.